# Which web development framework should I learn in 2020?

Tags: frameworks

There are so many web frameworks out there and I don't know which one I should really focus on. I know a bit of flask and ReactJS, but not enough to be an expert.

Answer (score 0):

No one would give you the correct answer to that, because everyone has specific needs, I really doubt the part where you said that you know react and flask, because, if you do, you wouldn't be looking for another framework to jump on since you said that you arent good wuth them.

Now, i would suggest that you learn Javascript very well, then move to a framework. it would also help to check out this article [Javascript](https://siitgo.com/blog/why-learn-the-javascript-programming-language/1623)